# Is it good to create/add index key for any column_name which is already created as primary/unique key

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql database.I have a registration table.The table structure is like that

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registration_doctors` 
(
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I have already created primary key and one unique key.I know when we create some column as a primary key or unique key then it works also as an index key.I want to use email as an index key.Now it will be good or not if i add email column as index.Because it is already unique key.Please help me.

Comment: Not sure I got that. But unique index is an index. The difference is that unique will not allow duplicates (it's obvious). So if you have unique index - you already have an index and, therefore,  you don't need to add new index for this column

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo thanks for your comment.I know it.But i am new developer.For this reason i wanted some advice from someone like you for being sure.Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You need to learn what index really is. It's not some magical thingy you add and then it makes stuff fly fast, it's a data structure that helps MySQL find where records are and it works exactly like an index of a book that you buy - it tells you at which page a chapter is. Unique, Primary etc. are all indexes, the only thing with primary/unique indexes is that they have only 1 distinct value. So as @AlmaDoMundo said - it's already an index and you don't need another one.

Answer (score 3):

1.indexes help `mysql` to search over your table faster,so index is good,but index should use in smart way,for example when you add all table field as index your search over your table will be so slow,instead fast!!!

2.primary key is one type of index,so when you add one field as primary key it's not necessary add it as index,because it`s index too!

I hope could help you.

Comment: Thank you so much.I agree with you.You are right.So i am not going to add index key on my table.Because i have already one primary key and one unique key.

Comment: search in a table by primary key is always faster and easier for mysql,so , only if you want to search by another field, make that field an index, else , you don't need that